# Access the richtextbox in the second form

Tags: c#, winforms

In my windows form application, I added two forms: `Form1` and `Form2`.
There is a button in `Form1` and a richtextbox in `Form2`.
What I expect is once I click the button in `Form1`, `Form2` is shown and also a file dialog displays.

Now I want to load a text from file to the rich text box, the question is how to access the richtextbox from the code?

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Hide();
                Form Form2 = new Form();
                Form2.Show();
                // load a text file to rich text box. How to access the rich text box here?
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to create an instance of Form2 and pass a string to its constructor, but it is not working.
[image]

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass text via Form2 constructor (you should modify its constructor or add new one):

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
Form2 form2 = new Form2(text);
form2.Show();
```

Here is how constructor should look like:

```
public Form2(string text)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    richtextbox.Text = text;
}
```

Bad solution: simply select richtextbox in designer and change its `Modifiers` property to `public`. You will break encapsulation of form, but control will be accessible outside Form2 class.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Love that's why I posted constructor code - you should modify it

Comment: But the .net framework doesn't support it. The constructor works for general class except for windows form likely.

Comment: @Love that's because you should create instance of `Form2`. Not base `Form` class. I haven't seen this mistake. Now updated

Comment: @Love then you haven't updated it. From your screenshot I still see `Form` instead of `Form2`

Comment: -@Sergey, sorry for ignorance, I still don't understand it. My code is exactly same as yours. I meant for Form2's constructor.

Comment: @Love No, it's not.  Your code should be `Form2 form2 = new Form2(text);`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, thank you very much. One more question, why the form is frozen and nothing in the richtextbox?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could declare the richtextbox from Form2 as public, or even declare a public property for loading data on it, and Access directly from Form1.

[Updated]

I may have explained it incorrectly. I meant make the richtextbox public, not just the form.

[image]

And after that just access to the control to load whatever you want:

```
Form2 objForm2 = new Form2(); 

        //Open file, etc... 

        objForm2.richTextBoxForm2.Text = "XXXX";
        objForm2.Show();
        objForm2.BringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Form1

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

In Form2

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            richTextBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
  }
}
```